# How do I replace all spaces, commas and periods in a variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried `var res = str.replace(/ |,|.|/g, "");` and `var res = str.replace(/ |,|.|/gi, "");`. What am I missing here?

```js
var str = "Text with comma, space, and period.";
var res = str.replace(/ |,|.|/g, "");
document.write(res);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you just want to delete all spaces, commas and periods you can do it like that:

```
var res = str.replace(/[ ,.]/g, "");
```

You can also use the `|` operator, but in that case you have to escape the period, because a plain period will match with any character. As a general remark, if in a regular expression you have multiple alternatives with `|` that all consist of a single character, it is preferable to use a set with `[...]`.

Comment: so clean this is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape dot `\.`:

```
"Text with comma, space and period.".replace(/ |,|\.|/g, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these lines:

```
str = str.replace(/[ ,.]/g,'');
```

Plus i have added a fiddle for this at [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ac8Lh7tn/)